# Font Effects in 8-Bit and 24-Bit Colour Representations

Tags: bash, colors, escape-characters

I want to use 8-Bit and 24-Bit colours in terminal, and have seen some different versions.

```
code="\e[38;5;${if}m"
code="\e[38;5;${ir};${ig};${ib}m"
```

I am unsure about the second number `5`, sometimes it is `2`.  Have read that it is also related to Font Effects.

Have also noticed that the Font Effect only affects the foreground and can be included separately (e.g. `\e[5m`).   Is this correct ?

```
code="\e[5m\e[38;5;${ir};${ig};${ib}m"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example

```bash
code="\e[38;5;${if}m"
code="\e[38;5;${ir};${ig};${ib}m"
```

the **5** is misused in the second case.  An RGB triple (using [direct colors](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-4-8-colon-2-colon-Pi-colon-Pr-colon-Pg-colon-Pb.2DC1)) would use a **2** in that position.  The first case with a single value is an [indexed color](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-4-8-colon-5-colon-Ps.2444).

The fragment `\e[5m` sets the [*blink*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-m:Ps-=-5.1DFE) attribute, which is different from color (on most terminals).

Further reading:

- [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
- [*Can I set a color by its number?*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#color_by_number) (in the XTerm FAQ)

Comment: I have seen  `"\e[31;1;4m"`  for setting text red (31), bold (1), underlined (4).  But I would like to use the format  `"\e[1;4m \e[31m"`.  They seem to be equivalent.  How about the 8-Bit and 24-Bit cases?  Would the same hold for font effects with prefixed format string  `"\e[1;4m"` ?